# Android NDK r10e "cannot find -lsupc++"

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm using VS2013 (with vs-android) to compile a native library, however, when using a static library i compiled (.a) i'm getting this error:

"cannot find -lsupc++"

actually i also get "error : cannot find -lgnustl_static" when compiling as GNU libstdc++ Static, how can i miss this many binaries?

I can't actually find libsupc++.a (which i actually have in an old directory with installed ndk r8d). Is libsupc++.a really missing in r10e ?

Any ideas to push me in the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, vs-android could not find those .a files. I specified manually my path to \android-ndk-r10e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a\ and the error disappeared. If anybody has any info on how to setup the proper way to let vs-android get those libraries, it would be great!